# Combine two cloud code functions to one function

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a notification screen in my iOS app that pulls requests from one table, and likes/comments from another. I want to make only one network call by calling a single function that returns both results of my two queries.

Here is my code it currently is functional:

Request Function

```
   Parse.Cloud.define("loadRequestNotifications", function(request, response){
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

   var query1 = new Parse.Query("Requests"); 
   query1.equalTo("requestUser", currentUser);

   var username = currentUser.get("username");     

   var query2 = new Parse.Query("Requests");
   query2.equalTo("driver", username);

    var main1 = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2); 
    main1.include("drivePointer");
    main1.include("drivePointer.driver");
    main1.limit(15);  

     main1.find({
      success: function(results) {

          response.success(results);

       },
      error: function(error) 
      {
        response.error(error);
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comments/Likes

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications", function(request, response) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

    var query3 = new Parse.Query("Posts"); 
    query3.equalTo("driver", currentUser); 

    var query4 = new Parse.Query("Posts");
    query4.equalTo("passengers", currentUser.get("objectId")); 

    var main2 = new Parse.Query.or(query3, query4); 

    var main3  = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main3.matchesKeyInQuery('postId', 'objectId', main2);

    var main4 = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main4.equalTo("commentBy", currentUser); 

    var activityQuery = new Parse.Query.or(main3, main4); 
    activityQuery.include("commentBy");
    activityQuery.limit(15); 

   activityQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
          response.success(results);
       },
      error: function(error) 
      {
        response.error(error);
      }
    });
});
```

I am using Parse SDK 1.1.12 for iOS and swift to call these functions. I want to be able to just call the combined one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like it:

```
function loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications (request) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

    var query3 = new Parse.Query("Posts"); 
    query3.equalTo("driver", currentUser); 

    var query4 = new Parse.Query("Posts");
    query4.equalTo("passengers", currentUser.get("objectId")); 

    var main2 = new Parse.Query.or(query3, query4); 

    var main3  = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main3.matchesKeyInQuery('postId', 'objectId', main2);

    var main4 = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main4.equalTo("commentBy", currentUser); 

    var activityQuery = new Parse.Query.or(main3, main4); 
    activityQuery.include("commentBy");
    activityQuery.limit(15); 

    return activityQuery.find();
}

Parse.Cloud.define("loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications", function(request, response){
    loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications(request).then(response.success, response.error);
});

...
// Similar code for loadRequestNotifications
...

Parse.Cloud.define("loadRequestAndLikesAndCommentsNotifications", function(request, response){
    loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications(request).then(function (results) {
        var finalResults = { likesAndComments: results};
        loadRequestNotifications(request).then(function (results) {
            finalResults.request = results;
            response.success(finalResults);
        }, response.error);
    }, response.error);
});
```

Comment: i have tried it and `Parse.Cloud.define("loadRequestAndLikesAndCommentNotifications")` isn't able to call the first function `loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications`

Comment: `TypeError: Object #<e> has no method 'catch'` is the error, is catch not allowed?

Comment: try .error(response.error) instead... I will edit the answer.

Comment: sorry... edited again... take a look in the updated answer.

Comment: thanks i did a variation of your code, but I will check this solution as well, looks more elegant.